# Image Not Upload On Local Folder In NiceEdit New Update

Tags: php, jquery, nicedit

friends after searching a lot over stackoverflow and google, I finally decide to ask this question as per my requirement for **niceEdit editor** as their new updated causes a little bit problem. I already download and call the **nicEdit.js** file as,

```
<script src="../nicEdit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and i also create **nicUpload.php**. Here is the PHP code, ( I just change the folder name )

```
<?php

define('NICUPLOAD_PATH', './uploads'); // Set the path (relative or absolute) to
                                      // the directory to save image files

define('NICUPLOAD_URI', '/uploads');   // Set the URL (relative or absolute) to
                                      // the directory defined above

$nicupload_allowed_extensions = array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif','bmp');

// You should not need to modify below this line

$rfc1867 = function_exists('apc_fetch') && ini_get('apc.rfc1867');

if(!function_exists('json_encode')) {
    die('{"error" : "Image upload host does not have the required dependicies (json_encode/decode)"}');
}

$id = $_POST['APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS'];
if(empty($id)) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') { // Upload is complete
    if(empty($id) || !is_numeric($id)) {
        nicupload_error('Invalid Upload ID');
    }
    if(!is_dir(NICUPLOAD_PATH) || !is_writable(NICUPLOAD_PATH)) {
        nicupload_error('Upload directory '.NICUPLOAD_PATH.' must exist and have write permissions on the server');
    }

    $file = $_FILES['nicImage'];
    $image = $file['tmp_name'];

    $max_upload_size = ini_max_upload_size();
    if(!$file) {
        nicupload_error('Must be less than '.bytes_to_readable($max_upload_size));
    }

    $ext = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file['name'], '.'), 1));
    @$size = getimagesize($image);
    if(!$size || !in_array($ext, $nicupload_allowed_extensions)) {
        nicupload_error('Invalid image file, must be a valid image less than '.bytes_to_readable($max_upload_size));
    }

    $filename = $id.'.'.$ext;
    $path = NICUPLOAD_PATH.'/'.$filename;

    if(!move_uploaded_file($image, $path)) {
        nicupload_error('Server error, failed to move file');
    }

    if($rfc1867) {
        $status = apc_fetch('upload_'.$id);
    }
    if(!$status) {
        $status = array();
    }
    $status['done'] = 1;
    $status['width'] = $size[0];
    $status['url'] = nicupload_file_uri($filename);

    if($rfc1867) {
        apc_store('upload_'.$id, $status);
    }

    nicupload_output($status, $rfc1867);
    exit;
} else if(isset($_GET['check'])) { // Upload progress check
    $check = $_GET['check'];
    if(!is_numeric($check)) {
        nicupload_error('Invalid upload progress id');
    }

    if($rfc1867) {
        $status = apc_fetch('upload_'.$check);

        if($status['total'] > 500000 && $status['current']/$status['total'] < 0.9 ) { // Large file and we are < 90% complete
        $status['interval'] = 3000;
    } else if($status['total'] > 200000 && $status['current']/$status['total'] < 0.8 ) { // Is this a largeish file and we are < 80% complete
        $status['interval'] = 2000;
    } else {
        $status['interval'] = 1000;
    }

        nicupload_output($status);
    } else {
        $status = array();
        $status['noprogress'] = true;
        foreach($nicupload_allowed_extensions as $e) {
            if(file_exists(NICUPLOAD_PATH.'/'.$check.'.'.$e)) {
                $ext = $e;
                break;
            }
        }
        if($ext) {
            $status['url'] = nicupload_file_uri($check.'.'.$ext);
        }
        nicupload_output($status);
    }
}


// UTILITY FUNCTIONS

function nicupload_error($msg) {
    echo nicupload_output(array('error' => $msg)); 
}

function nicupload_output($status, $showLoadingMsg = false) {
    $script = '
        try {
            '.(($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') ? 'top.' : '').'nicUploadButton.statusCb('.json_encode($status).');
        } catch(e) { alert(e.message); }
    ';

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
        echo '<script>'.$script.'</script>';
    } else {
        echo $script;
    }

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && $showLoadingMsg) {      

echo <<<END
    <html><body>
        <div id="uploadingMessage" style="text-align: center; font-size: 14px;">
            <img src="http://js.nicedit.com/ajax-loader.gif" style="float: right; margin-right: 40px;" />
            <strong>Uploading...</strong><br />
            Please wait
        </div>
    </body></html>
END;

    }

    exit;
}

function nicupload_file_uri($filename) {
    return NICUPLOAD_URI.'/'.$filename;
}

function ini_max_upload_size() {
    $post_size = ini_get('post_max_size');
    $upload_size = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
    if(!$post_size) $post_size = '8M';
    if(!$upload_size) $upload_size = '2M';

    return min( ini_bytes_from_string($post_size), ini_bytes_from_string($upload_size) );
}

function ini_bytes_from_string($val) {
    $val = trim($val);
    $last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);
    switch($last) {
        // The 'G' modifier is available since PHP 5.1.0
        case 'g':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'm':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'k':
            $val *= 1024;
    }
    return $val;
}

function bytes_to_readable( $bytes ) {
    if ($bytes<=0)
        return '0 Byte';

    $convention=1000; //[1000->10^x|1024->2^x]
    $s=array('B', 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB');
    $e=floor(log($bytes,$convention));
    return round($bytes/pow($convention,$e),2).' '.$s[$e];
}

?>
```

and this is how I call the niceEdit,

```
<textarea name="content" id="gMenuEdit" style="width:100%; height:250px;"></textarea> 
<script type="text/javascript">
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
    new nicEditor().panelInstance('gMenuEdit');
    new nicEditor({fullPanel : true}).panelInstance('gMenuEdit');
    new nicEditor({iconsPath : '../nicEditorIcons.gif'}).panelInstance('gMenuEdit');
    new nicEditor({buttonList : ['fontSize','bold','italic','underline','strikeThrough','subscript','superscript','html','image']}).panelInstance('gMenuEdit');
    new nicEditor({maxHeight : 100}).panelInstance('gMenuEdit');
    new nicEditor({uploadURI : 'http://localhost/projects/ci/adminPanel/nicUpload.php'}).panelInstance('gMenuEdit');
});
</script>
```

I want to upload the image in my uploads directory as i have mentioned in the php file but still the image is uploaded to the editer's default server path.

Comment: Search this 'xhr.open("POST", this.ne.options.uploadURI || this.nicURI);'
 in nicEdit.js and insert an alert() or console.log() statement to show what is in. I think uploadURI will be empty so  nicEdit use the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now after testing the new nicEdit.js and make a diff with the old one, not many changes, I test your problem.

The way you call nicEditors panelInstance is wrong.
After your first call the others have no effect.

Do it on this way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
   new nicEditor({
    fullPanel : true,iconsPath : '../nicEditorIcons.gif',
    buttonList : ['fontSize','bold','italic','underline','strikeThrough','subscript','superscript','html','image'],
    maxHeight : 100,
    uploadURI : 'http://localhost/projects/ci/adminPanel/nicUpload.php'
}).panelInstance('gMenuEdit');
});
</script>
```